# Can't print report from SQL Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, internet-explorer, reporting-services

I'm having an issue where I can view my reports in an ASP.NET environment, and can even export them, but as soon as I got print them, I  get the following javascript error:

> "Object doesn't support this property
>   or method"

When I run the debugger, I see the following code:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY onload="Print()">

        <OBJECT ID="RSClientPrint" CLASSID="CLSID:FA91DF8D-53AB-455D-AB20-F2F023E498D3" CODEBASE="?rs:Command=Get&rc:GetImage=8.00.1038.00rsclientprint.cab#Version=2000,080,1044,000" VIEWASTEXT></OBJECT>

        <script language="javascript">
        function Print()
        {
            RSClientPrint.MarginLeft = 6.35;
            RSClientPrint.MarginTop = 3.81;
            RSClientPrint.MarginRight = 6.35;
            RSClientPrint.MarginBottom = 3.81;

            RSClientPrint.PageHeight = 215.9;
            RSClientPrint.PageWidth = 355.6;

            RSClientPrint.Culture = 1033;
            RSClientPrint.UICulture = 9;

            RSClientPrint.Print("http://192.9.200.36/ReportServer", "%2fERSReports%2fGrossRequirements", "GrossRequirements")
        }
        </script>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have even tried doing this from the server, logged in as the Administrator ... and have set the security settings in IE to low and still get this error.

This was all working last week, and as far as I can tell, the only thing that may have happened is an update was pushed out by the server, which is probably the culprit.

Anyway, any idea how to work around this? My users desperately need to print these reports.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1541733&page=1

Check this thread. Sounds eerily similar to your problem.

Comment: @TheTXI Thanks! I'll let you know what I find out!

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/archive/2008/11/05/client-print-fails-to-load-after-microsoft-update-956391.aspx - this has a great explanation of the issue, so you can understand it.

Make sure you also install the report viewer redistributable on your app/web servers.  I was having another problem after I got past this one.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/933137